# Reading from string with optional parameters format C/C++

Tags: c, string, format, strtok, scanf

I am trying to parse the faces from an Wavefront OBJ file. These faces are specified in the file one by line, having the following format:

```
f v1/vt1/vn1 v2/vt2/vn2 ...
```

The sequence of triplets (v, vt, vn) is variable in length. Each triplet is separated by a space and each value inside a triplet is separated by a /.

So far so good, using `strtok` to separated the triplets and then parsing each triplet with
`sscanf` and the format `%f/%f/%f` works just fine. However in the specifications of the OBJ files, this line can have an alternative form, like this:

```
f v1//vn1 v2//vn2 ...
```

In this case the `vt` is missing and should be missing from all the triplets and the `sscanf` parse is not going to work.

Is there any way I can parse this in C or C++ in order to avoid nested `strtok`?

Comment: use [strsep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could first use the `%f//%f` format, and check the return value. If the return is less than two, do the `%f/%f/%f` format instead, which should work with both v, vt, and vtn.